# How do I exclude certain Vaadin views from authentication?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin22, vaadin-spring-boot

I want to make a couple of Vaadin (v22) views accessible without a login, i.e. make them publicly available.
I looked at this tutorial, which is probably outdated: https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security
There it says, that all views not using the `@Secured` annotation are publicly accessible. In my case it is different. Nothing is accessible at all, unless anotated with `@PermitAll` then logged in users can access the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ever so often, I found the answer while preparing the question.

The annotation to use is `@AnonymousAllowed`

Example:

```java
@Route(value = "/welcome", layout = PublicLayout.class)
@RouteAlias(value = "", layout = PublicLayout.class)
@AnonymousAllowed
public class PublicWelcomePage extends Div {
   // create your view here 
}
```

[Official Vaadin v22 docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/v22/fusion/tutorials/in-depth-course/login-and-authentication/#securing-vaadin-endpoints)

Comment: FYI, you can configure the authentication of a new project from start.vaadin.com.